# ¿Como eliminar parte de la cadena tras detectar un símbolo específico en ella?

Tags: java

Estoy intentado eliminar parte de una cadena conformada de la siguiente manera

URL_ORIGINAL = https://www.pagina.com/texto/frase_a_eliminar para dejarlo de está forma
URL_FINAL = https://www.pagina.com/texto/

¿De qué manera puedo realizar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer un substring desde la posición 0 hasta la posición del último `/`, se agrega `+1` para que se incluya el `/` al final:

```
String URL_FINAL = URL_ORIGINAL.substring(0,URL_ORIGINAL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```